# MYSQL fetch records from table only for a particular month

Tags: mysql

I want to fetch records from mysql table in monthly wise. I donot want to use `createDate BETWEEN "2015-04-01" and "2015-04-30"` nor `createDate > "2015-04-01" and createDate < "2015-04-30"`.

I have tried :

```
YEAR(createDate) = 2015 and MONTH(createDate) = 04  #which is not working.
```

can anyone tell me how write a query for any particular month.?

Comment: What's the problem with your query?

Comment: What you getting error in this?

Comment: The WHERE condition seems to be right. Would you explain "is not working" in detail please?

Comment: Just to be sure: typeof( createDate)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It should be

`MONTH(createDate) = 4`

however the approach

```
`createDate >= "2015-04-01" 
and createDate <= "2015-04-30"`
```

is much better since it would utilize the index, where in using the `YEAR` or  `MONTH` function will not use the index. For a small data-set its ok however for large data set it will overkill and the query will be very slow.

You can make it dynamic something as

```
where 
createDate >=  date_format(curdate(),'%Y-%m-01')
and
createDate <=  last_day(curdate())
```

For a particular month you can construct the query as

```
where 
createDate >=  date_format(curdate(),'%Y-04-01')
and
createDate <=  last_day(date_format(curdate(),'%Y-04-01'))
```